# How to create a file that has the properties of another and links to it when opened?

Tags: filesystems, file-attributes

I wonder if anyone knows if it is possible in Windows 7 to create a file (let's call it a source file) that represents another file, has it's properties (including size), but when opened actually opens another file (let's call it the target file)?

To clarify the use, here's why I want such a thing:

I have a large number of video files spread across a large number of HDD. I also have an application that creates a catalogue of these files. The problem is that the cataloging program needs to access all the files when it scans for new or updated files but I don't want (and am not able) to have all the HDDs connected/powered up in order to do this.

If I could create a file that represented each video file (but is not a copy of it) then I could point the cataloging program at a list of these files rather than the many HDDs. I understand that I would need to have the relevant HDD connected in order to actually play the files, and that I would more than likely have to create the source files manually, but that's no problem.

I might be asking the impossible...but hey, if you don't ask you don't get! :-)

***Edit***: Forgot to mention, SymLinks are not suitable in this case as they would require the target file to be accessible when the catalogue is scanned.

Comment: Could a basic shortcut do what you're asking?

Comment: @Bungicasse Only if the program he's using resolves shortcuts, otherwise a shortcut is a file in itself.

Comment: The “properties” of a video file are in the video file. So a surrogate file of whatever kind won’t cut it. You need the actual file and as such your plan cannot work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. You stated the cataloging program needs the target file to be accessible. I can imagine that the program is hashing the file, reading metadata or the content itself. I don't think any of this could help you:

- links,
- symlinks,
- hardlinks,
- junctions
- or even [some custom filesystem wrapper](https://dokan-dev.github.io/)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at symbolic links (or symlinks). Symlinks will allow you to create a link in one location pointing to a file or directory in a different location. For all intents and purposes, these symlinks behave as normal files and directories.

See also the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) and a tutorial on [HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/) explaining how to use `mklink`.

Comment: Thanks Roald, I did look at symlinks but I understood that when my cataloging program scans the symlink, the target file needs to be accessible, so it doesn't really help...unless I'm wrong about how symlinks work.

Comment: @daklone, you are correct. As far as I know, there's no solution to 'cache' the file information in a different location using something like symlinks or shortcuts. You should edit your question to put that information in there.